# Can one have good understanding on a method without having direct experience with it?

Tags: research, methodology, methods

This question is in line of these previous questions on other sites:

- [Is it possible to conduct scientific research without actually getting close to the sample/specimen?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/97318/6786) in Biology SE
- [Is it possible to have a scientific review of a method if the author doesn't have direct experience of it?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/78130/19487) in Philosophy SE

The overall conclusion of them is that, yes, it is possible to conduct scientific research/have valuable critiques on the samples or methods without having direct experience to them, *because one can work on the data*.

This makes me wonder: does this statement hold true in data science? In other sciences, scientists use method to extract data from samples. Since samples and data are different entities, therefore methods are not algorithms. But in data science, isn't that sample the data itself? Does data science only study methods/algorithms on how to process the data? (I suppose the study on new data format is more about computer science.) If yes, then cognitively, are data science methods different to other sciences methods?

Imagine a this scenario: I only have directly tried rule-based method. I have read introductions, researches, conversations of people have direct experience with statistical-based method, but never tried it once. Can I still be able to join conversations, debate on which method should be used in a classification problem, or even write good papers on LLM?

I think that in theory the answer is no different to other sciences. Having direct experience only help correct false assumptions quicker, but that shouldn't be a problem to the conversation partner who have direct experience with it. Is that correct?

Here I only limit the problem to terms you think you know. If you don't know a term then you acknowledge your limitation in knowledge and return to the listening mode. But if from the reading you think you know it, then you can form opinions. And if your opinions are formed incorrectly from your reading, then in a sense you are also hallucinated like LLM I guess?

Comment: I think this would depend on how abstract or how technical you want the conversation/discussion to go. Suppose, I only understand basic ML and probability theory, I can technically say well LLMs are simply producing some probability distribution for the next word/token in a sequence. But I have never worked with a LLM before, I barely know what a token is. But this information is sufficient to form a discussion about LLM applications IMO. But to discuss technical details such as query key, answers vectors, and the attention mechanism the above wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: that's a good point. However here I only limit the problem to terms you think you know. If you don't know a term then you acknowledge your limitation in knowledge and return to the listening mode. But if you think you know it, and you can form opinions, and that can limit your view/drain others' energy

Comment: That I do agree with that, I think that me personally have embraced the "no dumb question" philosophy, so if something I don't know gets mentioned, I will ask about it and hope the speaker will be able to explain, otherwise I think listening while being lost is not very productive for yourself either. But if you somewhat understand what is being talked about then I think it is sufficient to form opinions, or to formulate questions which imo is sufficient for a conversation. 
To address your question at the end, we are 100% LLMs, we will say everything with confidence until proven otherwise.